# I am looking for a font very similar to LITHOS PRO

Tags: font-identification

I am looking for a font, very similar to LITHOS PRO, 
that I once used in Photoshop but now I can't find it. Below is a photo of the font i am looking for. If anyone could please tell me the name?

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

The font in the image is [ITC Tempus Sans Std](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/tempus-sans/):

[image]

Welcome to GD.SE! For future reference, there are some requirements on this site for font-identification questions. These requirements along with helpful resources can be [found here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366).

Answer (score -1):

Trebuched MS is very simillar font.

Comment: Hi @Arkadiusz, welcome to GD.SE! Could you post an image of this typeface to back up your answer? This would help to improve quality of the answer. Thanks for contributing and have fun!